# PHP and MYSQL : How to implement login with facebook?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Hello I have searched the web for a few days now trying to figure out how to add login with facebook to my site. I found this video:    [Sign in with Facebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pWEzUv0aQ4) but it's really confusing. I want to add in login with Facebook using PHP and MySQL(not mysqli). I have setup the app on the Facebook developers page. I also already have my site hosted. The person in this video started going on about "composer" but he didnt explain what it is and why you need it. Can anyone answer these questions for me. What is composer and why do I need it for my sites "login with facebook" feature?

Comment: Maybe search Google for PHP Composer

Answer (score 0):

"Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the libraries your project depends on and it will manage (install/update) them for you."

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md